# Does moving references in Mendeley affect its citations in MS Word?

Tags: citations, reference-managers

I want to organise references in Mendeley (moving them in folders, etc.). Does this process will affect my recent citations in MS Word?

Comment: This is unclear. Presumably any citations you have made in public documents have nothing to do with your records in MS Word. How you choose to maintain citations for your own personal use is up to you.

Comment: What I mean I already used Mendeley to insert citations in MS Word. Now I want to update my Mendeley library by organising the files there into folders. Will this affect the citations I already inserted in MS Word?

Comment: Why not try it out with a test document and some test references? (My guess would be that it doesn't matter, as long as you don't change whatever cite key/id Mendeley uses).